# CheckBox inside ComboBox and sort data from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, ado.net

in ComboBox there is there are car brands
[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X5ut.png)

Here is the xaml

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Brand}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

and in Datagrid there are car models

Here is the xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Brand" Binding="{Binding Brands.Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Here is the code

```
private Brands selectedBrands;
        public ObservableCollection<Brands> Brand { get { return db.Brands.Local; } }
        public Brands SelectedBrand
        {
            get { return selectedBrands; }
            set
            {
                if (selectedBrands != value)
                {
                    selectedBrands = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedBrand));
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Cars));
                }
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<Car> Cars
        {
            get
            {
                if (SelectedBrand != null)
                    return db.Car.Local.Where(c => c.Brand == SelectedBrand.Id);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Now I need to sort the data using ComboBox, but I do not know how. Show me an example please or link

Comment: Sorting you can do with `.OrderBy` but what do you want to sort, and what is `SelectedBrand.ID` if `SelectedBrand` is a plural `Brands`?  In short, what exactly do you want to do, and what are you doing?

Comment: if Honda and Hyundai are selected in the ComboBox, then in the DataGrid only need to show the models of the selected brands

Comment: Can you fix your naming? You are using singular for plural items which makes it near impossible to understand your code. And where does _sorting_ get into your story?

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: Speak easier, I'm new, and I'm using Google translator

Answer (score 0):

From your comment: If Honda and Hyundai are selected in the ComboBox, then in the DataGrid only need to show the models of the selected brands

Then the below will work, I used Countries and Cities as example

You will need to set selected brand from combobox selection change event and set it

```
public ObservableCollection<City> Cities {
  get;
  private set;
}

private Country _selectedCountry;
public Country SelectedCountry {
  get {
    return _selectedCountry;
  }
  set {
    _selectedCountry = value;
    this.Cities.Repopulate(_selectedCountry.Cities);
  }
}
```

Comment: 'Repopulate' no such, I did not understand this? kind please tell me